# Nest 5.5 Error using BulkAll method

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

The BulkAll method is indexing all the correct records and returns health = green; but the BulkAllObservable is returning via the onError track with the following message:

Unsuccessful low level call on POST: /[*Index Name*]/[*Index Type*]/_bulk?pretty=true
**# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0028955

## ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: parse_exception Reason: "request body is required"

## OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.d__14`1.MoveNext()

## Request:

```
# Response:
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "request body is required"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "request body is required"
  },
```

We've tried varying the backoff time and batch size to no avail.

Method:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    return _elasticClient.BulkAll(capacities.Value, ba => ba
        .Index(indexName)
        .Type(IndexType)
        .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(_settingsHelper.GetBulkAllDegreeOfParallelism())
        // in case of 429 response (too many requests), how long we should wait before retrying
        .BackOffTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settingsHelper.GetBulkAllBackOffTimeoutInSeconds()))
        // in case of 429 response, how many times to retry before failing
        .BackOffRetries(_settingsHelper.GetBulkAllBackOffRetries())
        // number of documents to send in each request
        .Size(_settingsHelper.GetBulkAllBatchSize())
        .RefreshOnCompleted(),
        cancellationTokenSource.Token
    );
```

Calling code:

```
public async Task BuildIndex(string indexName)
{
    _logger.Debug($"MatchingIndexEngine - BuildIndex(indexName) - Index: {indexName}");

    Lazy<IEnumerable<Elastic.CarrierCapacity>> _lazyElasticCapacities;

    var indexExistsResponse = await IndexExistsAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (!indexExistsResponse)
    {
        await CreateIndexAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
        _lazyElasticCapacities = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Elastic.CarrierCapacity>>(GetPagedElasticCapacities);

        var handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var bulkAllObservable = _matchingIndexRepository.BulkAll(_lazyElasticCapacities, indexName);

        var observer = new BulkAllObserver(
            onNext: r =>
            {
                if (r.Page % (_settingsHelper.PagesPerLog()) == 0)
                {
                    _logger.Debug($"BulkIndexCapacitiesHandler - added batch {r.Page}");
                }
            },
            onError: async e =>
            {
                _logger.Error($"MatchingIndexEngine - error building index: {indexName} | Message: {e.Message} | Inner Exception: {e.InnerException} | Data: {e.Data}");

                await ActivateIndexAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var deprecatedIndexes = await GetDeprecatedMatchingIndexesAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await DeleteIndexesAsync(deprecatedIndexes).ConfigureAwait(false);

                throw new ElasticException($"MatchingIndexEngine - error building index: {indexName}");
            },
            onCompleted: async () =>
            {
                await ActivateIndexAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var deprecatedIndexes = await GetDeprecatedMatchingIndexesAsync(indexName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await DeleteIndexesAsync(deprecatedIndexes).ConfigureAwait(false);

                _logger.Info($"Rebuild of new index was successful - switched alias to new index: {indexName}.");
            }
        );
        bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(observer);


        handle.WaitOne();
        handle.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: May you post how do you compose bulk request?

Comment: Hey, Rob.  I posted the code here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924885/nest-5-5-bulkall-observable-error

Comment: Does `new Lazy<IEnumerable<Elastic.CarrierCapacity>>(GetPagedElasticCapacities).Value` contain `null` values?

Comment: Problem resolved -- I was mistaken in believing that all records were being indexed.  It turned out there were a couple records with null geopoint data (null lat and lon) that were failing.  My apologies for misleading and thanks for responses!  Russ was on the right track.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)